# Log4j writing to stdout on jboss 7

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x

In my web application I reinitialize log4j with my own log4j.xml file.

I already excluded my log4j.jar with following jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

After the reinitialization log4j logs everything in stdout

In jboss 5 I used this JVM param

```
-Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false
```

With jboss 7 this doesn't work. 
How can I configure log4j to not log to stdout?

Comment: Do you have a ConsoleAppendar in your configuration?

Comment: Yes I do. I use the same configuration as I did with jboss 5. If I remove it, jboss stops the console logging. It used to work fine with jboss 5

Comment: AFAIK you can't configure log4j not to us stdout. Are you using a specific appender that there is no equivalent Handler for?

Comment: No I don't use an appender without an equivalent handler.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no special appenders you use, you're probably best using the logging configuration that comes with the application server. It has the advantage of allowing you to make runtime changes from it's management interfaces (web console, CLI, etc.).

You can still use log4j as your logging facade in your application, but you just manage the loggers and handlers (appenders) from the application server.

Comment: Our application must support different application servers (weblogic, webshphere). It is not only jboss. That's why we have included log4j in the EAR and reinitialize it with our log4j.xml. Some of our customers have also their own log4j.xml which has to be supported as well. I think log4j can be initialized only once. When we initialize it again it thinks there is something wrong and forwards everything to stdout. The same issue we had with jboss 5 which we fixd with the mentioned property. I guess the only workaround would be to modify the formatter for the console appender in standalone.xml

Comment: log4j is not used in JBoss Application Server. There could be dependencies using, but the application server itself does not. It does however wrap stdout which could be what you're seeing. It still should print log messages, they just may not be formatted as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had to exclude the following two modules:

```
 <exclusions>
   <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
   <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
 </exclusions>
```